# How to Draw a rectangle on image using Emgu CV libraries in C#. with an example

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want to draw an rectangle on image using x & Y axis. it's very easy in python but unable to draw it in C# using OpenCV/Emgu CV libraries. I'm new to this please anyone have idea how do it.

Answer (score 1):

Most things you know how to do in Python with OpenCV can be done in C# Emgu with CvInvoke.

For instance, [this site](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/d43b7043-cd73-da1a-bec1-d5d78d61eecb.htm) shows the Rectangle method for drawing a rectangle onto a given image.

```
public static void Rectangle(
    IInputOutputArray img,
    Rectangle rect,
    MCvScalar color,
    int thickness = 1,
    LineType lineType = LineType.EightConnected,
    int shift = 0
)
```